Получить NFT изображения по адресу кошелька TON клиента, подключенного через TON connect через JavaScript
У меня есть веб-сайт на html и JS, к которым я подключила TON connect кошелёк. Казалось бы, всё хорошо работает, я могу подключить свой кошелёк через Telegram, но мне нужно следующее:

Узнать адрес кошелька пользователя, который подключил свой кошелёк TON

Нужно узнать, сколько item-ов конкретной NFT коллекции у него куплено на кошельке и лежат на нём. Есть конкретная коллекция, картинки которой пользователь может купить на другом сайте. Мне нужно только узнать, какие из этих картинок у него есть.

Нужно получить изображения этих картинок и отобразить уже на моём сайте.
Я пробовала разные библиотеки, но т.к. работаю впервые, мне не известна всякая разная документация и пр.,  долго разбиралась, получила только это (это мой код сейчас) :
 
 
 
     
     
     
     
     
     Tonium world
     
      -->
     
     
 
 
     
         
         <div class="buttons" id="buttons">
             <button class="button prev-btn" id="prev-btn">
                 Previous
             </button>
             <button class="button next-btn" id="next-btn">
                 Next
             </button>
             <div id="ton-connect" class="connect-ton"></div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <script type="module">
     const connector = new TON_CONNECT_UI.TonConnectUI({
         manifestUrl: "http://127.0.0.1:5500/tonconnect-manifest.json",
         buttonRootId: 'ton-connect'
     });
     console.log(connector)
     connector.uiOptions = {
         twaReturnUrl: 'https://t.me/Tonium world'
     };
     import{ libWeb } from "/node_modules/@tonclient/lib-web/index.js";
     console.log(libWeb)
     const tonweb = new TonWeb();
     const wallet = tonweb.wallet.create({publicKey});
 </script>    



Здесь я пыталась достать данные кошелька пользователя, но не получилось. Подскажите пожалуйста, какую библиотеку мне использовать, какие ИМЕННО файлы в ней (а то я не понимаю как подключать конкретный файл из библиотеки, если их куча. Среди многих ищу функцию TonClient на export, но ничего не нахожу)
Скажите, что нужно сделать, чтобы достать картинки из NFT коллекции и скиньте документацию об этом. Очень надо
Я пробовала библиотеку ton, tonweb, и всякое разное, но толком не разобралась, какие ИМЕННО файлы мне нужно было подключать, чтобы узнать хотя бы адрес кошелька.
GPT мне выдал следующее:
const { TonClient } = require("@tonclient/core");
const { libWeb } = require("@tonclient/lib-web");
TonClient.useBinaryLibrary(libWeb);

// Создание экземпляра клиента TON
const client = new TonClient({
  network: {
    server_address: 'https://main.ton.dev' // адрес сервера блокчейна TON
  }
});

// Получение адреса кошелька клиента через TON Connect
async function getClientWalletAddress() {
  try {
    const { address } = await client.getFullContractState({
      address: { '@type': 'MsgAddressInt', workchain_id: -1, address: '-1:3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333' } // адрес контракта TON Labs Multisig Wallet
    });
    console.log('Адрес кошелька клиента:', address);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Ошибка при получении адреса кошелька клиента:", error);
  }
}

// Вызов функции для получения адреса кошелька клиента
getClientWalletAddress();

всё бы хорошо, но TonCLient я так и не могу определить, т.к. не понимаю, из какого ИМЕННО файла в @tonclient/core мне нужно брать функцию TonCLient. Я обыскала всё, подключила сто пятьсот библиотек, но так  не поняла, где это искать. Буду рада, если дадите развёрнутый ответ на этот вопрос

Добро пожаловать! Прочтите справку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking. Вопрос должен быть сконцетрирован на одной проблеме. Сейчас я вижу 3, скорее всего вопрос закроют без ответа, если это не исправить
